# How to Align Item at the bottom of the screen In material ui

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to align button at the end of the screen so that even if i scroll background list still the button should remain at the bottom of the screen. I tried and unable to figure this out. Anyone please help me to do so.

This is how my screen looks like.
Right Now it always come in the middle of the screen while scrolling .
[image: Scroll Image]

Here is My code for this

```
<Link to={"/checkout-summary"}>
          <div className="checkoutbtn">
            <Button
              style={{
                boxShadow: "none",
                borderRadius: "0px",
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 0
              }}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
            >
              Check Out
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Link>
```

Comment: Move the button after the content, it looks like you have specified height before the button. you can try `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the footer to the bottom

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  footer: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 60,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
}));

const classes = useStyles();

<Link to={"/checkout-summary"} className={classes.footer}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
    
const MyMessageBox = styled('div')({
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 60,
    textAlign: 'center',
});
      
<MyMessageBox>Contents inside this will be shown at the bottom of the page</MyMessageBox>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).